# odd .bat file behavior

Tags: java, windows, character-encoding, batch-file

I have a bat file with the following contents:

```
set logfile=  D:\log.txt

java com.stuff.MyClass %1 %2 %3  >> %logfile%
```

when I run the bat file though, I get the following:

```
C:\>set logfile= D:\log.txt

C:\>java com.stuff.MyClass <val of %1> <val of %2> <val of %3>   1>>D:\log.txt
The parameter is incorrect.
```

I'm almost positive the "The parameter is incorrect." is due to the extraneous 1 in there.  I also think this might have something with the encoding of the .bat file, but I can't quite figure out what is causing it.  Anyone ever run into this before or know what might be causing it and how to fix it?

**Edit**

And the lesson, as always, is check if its plugged in first before you go asking for help.  The bat file, in version control, uses D:\log.txt because it is intended to be run from the server which contains a D drive.  When testing my changes and running locally, on my computer which doesn't have a D drive, I failed to make the change to use C:\log.txt which is what caused the error.  Sorry for wasting you time, thanks for the help, try to resist the urge to downvote me too much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may seem like a stupid question, but is there an existing D: drive in the context that the bat file runs in?

Once I had a case where a bat file was used as the command line of a task within the Task Manager, but the Run As user was set to a local user on the box, giving no access to network drives.

Interpolated for your case, if the D: drive were a network drive, running the bat file as, say, the local administrator account on that machine instead of a domain user account would likely fail to have access to D:.

Comment: thanks, that was it.  I did notice the error and fixed it before your response, but you managed to nail it.

Answer (score 3):

I doubt that that's the problem - I expect the command processor to deal with that part for you.

Here's evidence of it working for me:

Test.java:

```
public class Test
{
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
    {
        System.out.println(args.length);
        for (String arg : args)
        {
            System.out.println(arg);
        }
    }
}
```

test.bat:

```
set logfile= c:\users\jon\test\test.log
java Test %1 %2 %3 >> %logfile%
```

On the command line:

```
c:\Users\Jon\Test> [User input] test.bat first second third

c:\Users\Jon\Test>set logfile= c:\users\jon\test\test.log

c:\Users\Jon\Test>java Test first second third  1>>c:\users\jon\test\test.log

c:\Users\Jon\Test> [User input] type test.log
3
first
second
third
```

Answer (score 2):

the 1 is not extraneous: it is inserted by cmd.exe meaning stdout (instead of ">>", you can also write "1>>". contrast this to redirecting stderr: "2>>"). so the problem must be with your parameters.